# Is it safe to add web.config on IIS 6 server running volusion

Tags: web-config, volusion

My client site is running Volusion an ecommerce site currently running too slow when it comes to page speed. I would like to try add this web.config and do some tweaks to fix those recommendations from GTMetrix.com.

I have done it on site using IIS 7 Server but running in WordPress.

Any ideas on how to improve site pagespeed running in volusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to modify any server configuration settings on Volusion. Any server access of this nature is locked down.

If you want to improve page speed on a Volusion store, you need to look to page speed optimization techniques that are more focused on reducing file size and http requests such as those suggested by Page Speed Insights.

Comment: What do you mean by **Any server access of this nature is locked down?**. you mean any changes you made from the server and your store will be lock down or unable to access your web server files?

Comment: While you have FTP access, you do not have access to the root folder nor will the server be utilizing a config file. And, yes, you cannot access the web server itself. You effectively have access to add/remove/ edit one directory underneath public_html.